# In BigQuery column recognized if I select *, but not when I specify a column (trying to unpivot)

Tags: google-bigquery

In BigQuery why is it that

```
create or replace table `xxx.users.active users` 
as select *  from `xxx-check.users.users`
unpivot(Active_Users for Days in (Active_30, Active_45, Active_60, Active_90));
```

works fine, but when I

```
create or replace table `xxx.users.active users` 
as select Primary_Email, Active_30, Active_45, Active_60, Active_90  from `xxx-check.users.users`
unpivot(Active_Users for Days in (Active_30, Active_45, Active_60, Active_90));
```

generates an error Unrecognized name: Active_30 when Active_30 is a column in the .users table.

Answer (score 0):

> Unrecognized name: Active_30 when Active_30 is a column in the .users table.

--> You can only access columns in the result table after being unpivoted.

If you want to have specific columns left in the unpivoted table, you should select columns you want in the subquery like below.

```sql
-- sample data
WITH `xxx.users.active users` AS (
  SELECT 'foo' dummy, 'a@b.com' Primary_Email, 10 Active_30, 20 Active_45, 30 Active_60, 40 Active_90
)
-- query starts here
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT Primary_Email, Active_30, Active_45, Active_60, Active_90 FROM `xxx.users.active users`
) UNPIVOT (
  Active_Users FOR Days IN (Active_30, Active_45, Active_60, Active_90)
);

--query result
+---------------+--------------+-----------+
| Primary_Email | Active_Users |   Days    |
+---------------+--------------+-----------+
| a@b.com       |           10 | Active_30 |
| a@b.com       |           20 | Active_45 |
| a@b.com       |           30 | Active_60 |
| a@b.com       |           40 | Active_90 |
+---------------+--------------+-----------+
```